# Playing mp3 on my website

Tags: mp3, media-player

So I was wondering what the best way to play an mp3 on my website would be...

I kind of want it to function and appear like the itunes method - a simple play and stop button. like this:

[image]

How should I do this? I don't really want to embed a player.

Thanks for the help!
Add to Bookmarks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use:

```
<embed height="50px" width="100px" src="song.mp3" />
```

But this will also show a visible player in most cases.

Another way to do this is using the audio tag from HTML5 (not supported in older browsers):

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

(Using 2 sources here because most browsers either support ogg or mp3. But usually not both)

The tag shown will generate a controllable (invisible) audio element on your page.
You could then use JavaScript to control the audio element with a custom button for example:

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('audio').play()">Play</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('audio').pause()">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention - simple play and stop button but HTML5 have pause and play button.Have a try.

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

without using embed player, that's very hard to code the whole player. Have a look at 
[Jplayer](http://jplayer.org/)